# Serving Videos via HTTP to my LAN

Tags: website, media, kodi

I've got a number of movies and TV episodes with full metadata on my machine.  I want to be able to access these videos from other machines on my network.  I've got all the network stuff set up, but I'm looking for a nice web app that can show me what I've got along with all of the metadata.  I'd prefer it to be hosted under IIS, but I'll bite the bullet and use Apache if I have to.

To be more succinct, I'm looking for XBMC, but feeding metadata via HTTP and providing links to the movies (which I can then stream).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably dozens of products, but i use [Twonky](http://twonky.com) for this purpose (on a small linux server). It's a [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA)/UPnP-Server, it scans given directories for media files and serves them primarily to TV-Sets, Phones etc., but there's also a web-view (html or flash):

[image]

It's commercial software ($20), one may try it out for 30 days afaik. It's available for Windows/Mac/Linux. The web server is integrated.